# WPF DataGrid can't select a row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I filled a `DataGrid` with a binding of `List<>` containing objects. I can make them appear in the  `DataGrid`, but the problem is, I just can't select a row. When I added `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`, the first row appeared to be selected (blue background of the row) but I couldn't change it, not even removing it. Here's what my `DataGrid` in XAML looks like :

```
<Window x:Class="ClientTrackerWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="560" Width="594" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
    <Grid>
         <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="231" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,2,0,0" Name="datagridClients"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="datagridClients_SelectionChanged"
                  SelectionMode="Single" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prénom" MinWidth="175" Binding="{Binding Path=_prenom}" />
                      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom" MinWidth="175" Binding="{Binding Path=_nom}" />
                      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Téléphone" MinWidth="150" Binding="{Binding Path=_telephone}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
         </DataGrid>
     </Grid>
</Window>
```

I tried looking here and on google but couldn't find something useful for me. By the way, I'm using C#.

Here is the C# part.

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

    namespace ClientTrackerWPF
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Logique d'interaction pour MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            BDD bdd;
            List<Client> listeClients;
            bool started = false;

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void initilisationApp()
            {
                bdd = new BDD();
                bdd.startConnection("clients.sqlite");

                listeClients = new List<Client>();
                listeClients = bdd.getAllClients();
                datagridClients.ItemsSource = listeClients; //The source of the binding

                tabMain.IsEnabled = true;
                menuFileInit.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                menuFileNewClient.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                started = true;
            }

            private void menuFileInit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                initilisationApp();
            }
            private void datagridClients_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Source);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks !

Comment: Show the `columns` section of the grid.

Comment: Make sure that in datagridClients_SelectionChanged you've not set the Handled property of the event args. e.Handled = true;

Comment: I edited my code and added the columns. @Andy I tried with e.Handled = true; but it didn't change anything, in fact, I'm learning C# WPF so my code is pretty basic.

Comment: @Stealthunter post your C# code altogether with the full XAML

Comment: @HighCore here, I added the C# part and some more XAML.